# Dokku: Prevent rogue domain from getting served by nginx

Tags: nginx, dokku

I have a simple Rails application running in a Dokku instance. I have my own domain pointing to it, but I also found there is a rogue domain pointing to my server. The rogue domain gets also served by my Dokku based application.

Guestion: How can I prevent Dokku from serving other than the domain I have specified?

I guess I could have something like `server { return 404 }` in nginx.conf file, but I'm not sure how Dokku plays with these nginx configurations..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set server_name for you domain only:

```
server {
   server_name your.domain;
   ...
}
```

and yes, you can wrap rogue domain with server {} too

```
server {
   server_name rogue.domain;
   return 404;
}
```

place it into http {} section (nginx.conf OK)

Dokku: App specific Nginx configuration can be set for example with [dokku-nginx-alt plugin](https://github.com/mikexstudios/dokku-nginx-alt). There is also conversation related to dokku and nginx.conf in [this](https://github.com/progrium/dokku/issues/271) github issue.

Comment: Yep, this about the thing that I already knew. But how is this all done with Dokku?